# git not found in your path, where is not recognised by internet or externel command

Tags: flutter

I am installing flutter and I got these errors `********git not found in your path, where is not recognized by internet or external command***`***** how to fix that??

Comment: Install git and add it to your path.

Comment: Download and install git first, https://git-scm.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

In flutter installation steps it specifies that you need to have a git installed on your computer.

...
System requirements
...
. Git for Windows 2.x, with the Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt option.
...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comman *"git --version"* in the CMD to verify if you installed Git correctly.
If you do, you shuld see something like this: *git version 2.24.0.windows.2*.